# Acessing parent object fields/methods in Clojure

Tags: reflection, clojure, awt

I have a java.awt.Frame that is a descendent of java.awt.Component. I'm trying to get the `peer` field of the Component, or else call `.getPeer` on it.

```
(def f (new Frame "AWT test"))              
(. f setSize 400 400)
(. f setLayout (new GridLayout 3 1))
(class f)          ;;java.awt.Frame
(supers (class f)) ;; #{java.awt.Container java.io.Serializable java.awt.Window java.awt.image.ImageObserver java.awt.Component java.awt.MenuContainer java.lang.Object javax.accessibility.Accessible}
```

I can see that `Component` is a superclass, but can't figure out how to access it.

```
(filter #(instance? java.awt.Component %) (supers (class f))) ;; () - it returns empty
```

Yes, I know `getPeers` is deprecated. I'll likely need to do some reflection work after I get the `Component`. And I already have the requisite `add-opens` in play.

Answer (score 0):

You just call `(.getPeer f)`, like any other method. No fancy business is required to call a public method, whether declared in this class or in a superclass. Of course, this only works if you're using a version of Java old enough to support this method.

Comment: No, that doesn't work:
"No matching field found: getPeer for class java.awt.Frame
Clojure: class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"

Comment: The method seem to have been removed - at least, it's not there in JDK 17.

Comment: Then I need to get the field containing the peer using reflection and use that directly. But to do that, I think the first step is getting a reference to the `Component`.
That said, `getPeer` seems to be there in the latest OpenJDK: 
https://github.com/openjdk/client/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/java/awt/Component.java#L931

Comment: That is the `getPeer` method of a different class: an inner class of Component, not Component itself. There is no `getPeer` method to call. There's a non-public field, which you can get with reflection if you're not running in a sandbox that prevents `setAccessible`. Getting a reference to Component is, in a sense, the first step: you already have one, because Frame is a subclass of Component. There's no special way to get a "Component-like view" of it or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't have a clear answer of how to filter by the class, but I did find a way to get the peer component:

```
(def acc (AWTAccessor/getComponentAccessor))
(.getPeer acc f);; #object[sun.awt.X11.XFramePeer 0x2fa3dc81 "sun.awt.X11.XFramePeer@2fa3dc81(7600007)"]
```

That's good enough for now.